# Zend form validation multiple custom validation message for same field at the same time

Tags: forms, validation, zend-framework, message

I have a Zend form password custom validation.

I have set the `addValidator` functions `IInd` argument to false since I need to get all errors at once. Both of my validation classes have set the `self::INVLID` to corresponding error messages.

But when I look in the Zend controller even though both validations fail I'm getting only one (the last) error message.

I need all the error messages at once.

```php
    /* Form validation*/
    $passwordSpecialValidator = new Passwordspecialvalidationvalidator();
    $passwordHistoryValidator = new Passwordhistorylvalidationvalidator(new model(), $username, $newpass);

    $this->newpass->addValidator($passwordSpecialValidator, false)
            ->addValidator($passwordHistoryValidator, false);

    /* One validation class */

    class Passwordhistorylvalidationvalidator extends Zend_Validate_Abstract {

        const INVLID = '';

        protected $_messageTemplates = array(
            self::INVLID => 'Your password doesnt meet the history requirements'
        );

        public function __construct($model, $username, $password) {
            $this->_model = $model;
            $this->_username = $username;
            $this->_password = $password;
        }

        public function isValid($value, $context = null) {

            if ($this->_username == "") {
                $auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
                if ($auth->hasIdentity()) {
                    $arrayResult = $auth->getIdentity();
                    if (isset($arrayResult->username)) {
                        $this->_username = $arrayResult->username;
                    }
                }
            }
            $passwordExists = false;
            $oldPasswords = $this->_model->getHistoryPasswords($this->_username, $this->_password);

            if (count($oldPasswords) > 0) {
                $passwordExists = true;
            }

            if ($passwordExists == false) {
                return true;
            } else {
                $this->_setValue($value);
                $this->_error(self::INVLID);
                return false;
            }
        }


    }
    /* Getting error messages */
    foreach ($objForm->getMessages() as $messages) {
        foreach ($messages as $message) {
            $errMessages[] = $message;
        }
    }
```

---

But the array `$errMessages` has only the last validation message (without index) even though both special validation and history validation fails. How would I get both error messages in an array if both validations fail?

Comment: Please identity you code better.

Comment: I have edited the code portion for more readability.